# Magento 2.4 showing 404 not found for product page loadeds from a different store view

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, magento2.4, product-urls, redirect-url

I have a Magento 2.4.1 store with two languages (EN and DE). Let's say the EN store view is currently selected and a product URL will look like this: https://website.de/wedding-bands/wedding-band-1.html.

I may give this URL to a customer, but he has the DE language currently selected. So, when he tries to access this URL, it will give a 404 Not Found error, because the actual URL for that product is different in the DE shop (https://website.de/eheringe/eheringe-1.html).

What's the best way of fixing this so that it will return the correspondent DE product URL even if I give the EN product URL?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you are already saving the product URLs at store view level, your only option is to create custom rewrites for the product so that the product 'responds' to both URLs.

You can use Magento's URL Rewrites functionality and add rewrites in the following format:
[image]

In my example, my product has the URL 'joust-duffle-bag.html' in my 'Default store view', but has URL 'joust-duffle-bag2.html' in anothere storeview. So by adding a rewrite, I am telling Magento that I want 'joust-duffle-bag2.html' to point to 'joust-duffle-bag.html' if requested on my store view.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying to my question!

Indeed, this is a proper solution, but I would like to avoid generating new rewrites and somehow do this through the code.

I am close by using an observer for the 'controller_front_send_response_before' event, having the following code.

```
$fullUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
    $baseUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl();

    if(isset($fullUrl) && $fullUrl != "" && isset($baseUrl) && $baseUrl != "") 
    {
         $searchString = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $fullUrl);

        if($searchString != "") {
            $urlRewrite = $this->_urlRewrite->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('request_path', $searchString);

            if(isset($urlRewrite) && is_array($urlRewrite->getData()) && sizeof($urlRewrite->getData()) > 0) {
                foreach($urlRewrite->getData() as $rewriteItem) 
                {
                    if($rewriteItem['entity_type'] != 'product') {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($rewriteItem['store_id']);

                    if($store->getData('is_active') == 1) {
                        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($rewriteItem['store_id']);
                        $storeCode = $store->getCode();
            
                        $this->_httpContext->setValue(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::ENTITY, $storeCode, $storeCode);
                        $this->_storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);
                        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($store);                             

                        break;
                    }
                }

                $this->_cacheManager->clean(['full_page']);
            }
        } 
    }
```

The only problem I have is with the FPC that is not cleared on time.

Do you have a solution for this?
What do you think about my approach?